# Why doesn't it update the ui then run the code wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, user-interface, ftp

I have this code where I upload some streams to an ftp server. But before that I want to make the spinnerContainer visible. But if I call the method it freezez (It started uploading) and only show the container after it's finished.

```
spinnerContainer.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;

client.Connect();
client.EmptyDirectory(Id);
client.SetWorkingDirectory(Id);
for (int i = 0; i < streams.Count; i++)
{
    client.UploadStream(streams[i], i.ToString());
}
client.Disconnect();
```

**I want to run the** `spinnerContainer.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;` **first** then the rest. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code runs on the UI thread, so until the UI method completes execution, the UI thread will be blocked and the GUI will not update.
Use asynchrony:

```cs
private async Task SomeMethod()
{
    spinnerContainer.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;

    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        client.Connect();
        client.EmptyDirectory(Id);
        client.SetWorkingDirectory(Id);
        for (int i = 0; i < streams.Count; i++)
        {
            client.UploadStream(streams[i], i.ToString());
        }

        client.Disconnect();
    });

}
```

The call of the method has to be awaited:

```
await SomeMethod();
```

In case you are calling it from an event handler, the handler method must be declared `async void`.

Comment: Or `private Task SomeMethod()` with `return Task.Run(...)`.

Comment: @Clemens , In general, I agree with you.
But in this particular case, I'm almost 100% sure that this code is called by a button clicker or other event. And events require "void" methods.

Comment: Then the event handler would be async void. The only exception to the rule are event handlers. You should add that to your answer, because it is important.